# Deleting all records from room db

Tags: android

I can't get to erase all past records in my room db using both queries, I tried different other approaches but nothing seems to be working for me, here is my code

This is my service class after storing the date from json response to compare with later

```
   //// storing the date from json response

   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 
   MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
   editor.putString("date", datetime);
   editor.apply();

   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 
   MODE_PRIVATE);
  String getDate = sharedPreferences1.getString("date", null);

        ///this is the method which is supposed to delete the data 

        DeleteOld(getDate);
```

and this is the piece of code i used to compare dates and if the difference is equals to 2 days , delete that all data

```
 @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    public void DeleteOld(String dataDate) {

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 
         HH:mm:ss");


        try {
            Date pasTime = simpleDateFormat.parse(dataDate);
            Date nowTime = new Date();

            long difference = nowTime.getTime() - pasTime.getTime();

            long day = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(difference);

            if (day == 2) {
                new Thread(() -> {
                    AppDataBase appDataBase = 
              DbClient.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getDataBase();
                    appDataBase.liveModelDao().deleteAllData(new LiveModel());
                }).start();
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

and i used these queries to delete data but i dont know wether they are the issue or something else

```
 @Query("DELETE FROM livetable")
    void deleteAll();

    @Delete
    void deleteAllData(LiveModel model);
```

as result of this code, I want to actually delete all data of my room db after 2 days, and to do that I get my json api date, store and format it, then try to subtract it from the nowtime to get the difference converted from milliseconds to days and then compare if the difference of both days is equal to 2, then delete data.

Comment: The `deleteAllData(new LiveModel())` actually deletes nothing, since it's a new instance. What's wrong with `deleteAll();`?

Comment: what i want to acheive is to delete the whole data from room db each 5 days  , and i cant get to make the code work and when i launch the app , the data is not deleted from db after setting the device to +5 days in future .

Comment: i passed that new instance for testing purpose but i usually pass livemodel object